# Git popping strange errors in Jenkins after my project changed of gitlab group

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I have a project, which git URL is :
git@gitlab.mycomp.fr:mygroup/myproject.git

I've just changed it from an other group to "mygroup".

Now, when I do `git clone git@gitlab.mycomp.fr:mygroup/myproject.git` it works perfectly.

But Jenkins is not using "git clone" command, it uses :

```
git init /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/PROJET/workspace
```

then :

```
git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.mycomp.fr:mygroup/myproject.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

which ends in :

```
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

I've tried to create a new Jenkins project to get rid of any cache problem, but it has the same result.

Comment: Does your Jenkins user have enough privileges to act in the new group as well?

Comment: I guess the best answer is : Jenkins key is not allowed to clone from this new group.

Comment: @AKX, yeah I think you're right. After writing the whole thing, it appears to me too  :)